# Gernerate List using Entity Framework and lambda expressions in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

For my own practice I'm building a small ASP.NET website that shows data content of an existing database.

To work with the database I'm using Entity Framework and I want to use lambda expressions in connection.

Actual I got 6 tables in my database:

1. `Projects` (ID, ProjectName)
2. `Categories` (ID, CategoryName)
3. `Users` (ID, UserName)
4. `Parts` (ID, PartName)
5. `ProjectCategoryPart` (ProjectID, CategoryID, PartID, PartExists)
6. `ProjectCategoryUser` (ProjectID, CategoryID, UserID)

   - Each `Project` has `n` `Categories`
   - Each `Category` has `1` `User`
   - For each `Project` and `Category` there are `n` `Parts` with an `PartExists`-Flag

Now I want to create a list that contains the following information for one of the projects inside of table one

```
Category       User                Parts Left       Total Parts
Category_1     RelatedUserName     PartCountLeft    PartCountTotal
Category_2     RelatedUserName     PartCountLeft    PartCountTotal
Category_n     RelatedUserName     PartCountLeft    PartCountTotal
```

Here for example one code Line I'm actually using to get the data of a project out of the table Projects:

```
myList = DatabaseEntities.Projects.Single(project => project.Number == sendNumber);
```

Can someone help me with the code I need to create the List?

Up to now I'm only able to create simple database requests because it was hard for me to find examples that are showing more than this.

Comment: I would shore up your design first. It apears a project can have many users and a user can have many projects (many-to-many). Then you need a category attribute on the relationship/bridge table (ProjectUsers).

Comment: sorry, there are some informations missing that I've changed now. In the ProjectParts Table is also a Column for the Category.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, your design may need some work, but if you are trying to focus in on the aggregation portion you can work around it. If your classes have navigation properties similar to this:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    // if you want multiple users you will need to change this
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }  // nav to user

    public ICollection<ProjectPart> ProjectParts { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectPart
{
    public int PartId { get; set; } // Be consistent and call this ID as below
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public bool? PartExists { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }  // nav to project
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I would build a viewmodel for the results:

```
public class ProjectPartViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PartsCount { get; set; }
    public int PartsExistCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then the query:

```
var projectPartCounts = context.ProjectParts.AsNoTracking()
    .GroupBy(pp => new { pp.CategoryName, pp.Project.User.UserName })
    .Select(g => new PropjectPartsViewModel {
        Category = g.Key.CategoryName,
        Name = g.Key.UserName,
        PartsCount = g.Count(),
        PartsExistCount = g.Count(pp => pp.PartsExist == true)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: you're right, it's very smelly :-) I think/hope the real design I'm using isn't that smelly. I've tried to extract some part of my program for a better explanation of my problem but it looks like it didn't work. :-(  I'll try to make some changes in my post for a better understanding ;-)

Comment: I've added one table for Categories so the code should be more generic. Does this make more sense now? :-)

Comment: Category sounds like a simple lookup table (ID + DESCRIPTION). Why would you add a ProjectId and UserId? Try to think about the relational design at a higher level (entities). Unless your labeling if off, the relationships sound pretty standard: A project has many users, a user has many projects (many-to-many). A project has many parts, a part has a single project (1-to-many). A project part (or perhaps project?) has a category, a category can have many project or project parts (1-to-many). You don't need to add FKs everywhere since EF and SQL allow you to get there via references.

Comment: Here is a good overview: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry for this confusion. Another try as you can see above: Different Tables for Project, Category, User, Part. And two tables for the relationship. Normally I only got problems to create the code and not the relations itself. :-( The User is related to the category and not to the Project itself.

Comment: This is why my first comment was to shore up the relational design first. You end up writing a lot of code that does not apply if your design is wrong. In a [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) database, the queries flow naturally (in most cases).

Comment: I totally agree and I already got a relational design but due to the fact that I tried to extract only a part of the design I messed up everything :-(

Comment: I tried to create an example out of my project because I want to ask for a solution only for one part and use the solution to solve the next problems by myself. I hope the actual example I create make sense and it is possible to create a code for it, that makes sense